# React App showing dark theme after installing daisyUI

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, daisyui

I have installed tailwind css then installed daisyUI. After running my react app it is showing dark theme. I want to remove it.
Here is the ***tailwind.config.js*** file.

````
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
};```
````

Answer (score 4):

You can remove all themes by adding these lines to exports object in your **tailwind.config.js**

```
daisyui: {
   themes: false,
}
```

Like this:

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  daisyui: {
     themes: false,
  }
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
};
```

This way you are left with **light theme** only.

Or you can include only the themes you require using this configuration.

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  daisyui: {
     themes: ["cupcake", "cmyk"],
  }
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
};
```

Refer to [docs](https://daisyui.com/docs/themes/) for more details.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Tried not working. Looks like the problem is in "plugins: [require("daisyui")]" here. After removing this code the dark theme goes away so is the styles.

Comment: But that would completely remove daisyui from your app. I've tried and tested the solution. Setting `themes: false` should work. Make sure your implementation is correct.

Comment: And remove `data-theme` attribute from body element if you've attached it while installing **daisyui**.

Comment: `themes: false` doesn't work. I removed everything but `content` and `plugins` and still showing dark theme. There was no data-theme but I added one setting the color light. Now it' showing white background. Now the problem is when I set some custom theme inside `daisyui: {
     themes: ["cupcake", "cmyk"],
  }` and use those in my project they don't work.

Comment: If you are using `theme-change`, check localStorage theme setting.

Answer (score 1):

You should set daisyui.themes to empty array, setting it to false will still load light and dark themes.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [require('daisyui')],
  daisyui: {
    themes: [],
  },
};
```

make sure you stop and rerun the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add daisyui (and **react-daisyui** if you use it too) in the content array of tailwind.config.js, so tailwind does not purge daisyUI styles. See [react-daisyui installation instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-daisyui#-install).

```js
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './index.html',
    './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    'node_modules/daisyui/dist/**/*.js',
    'node_modules/react-daisyui/dist/**/*.js',
  ],
  daisyui: {
  themes: [],
  },
  plugins: [require('daisyui')],
};
```